# Extension methods on a static class?

Tags: c#, extension-methods, static-classes

I know i can do the below to extend a class. I have a static class i would like to extend. How might i do it? I would like to write `ClassName.MyFunc()`

```
static public class SomeName
{
    static public int HelperFunction(this SomeClass v)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> **You can't have extension methods on static classes because extension methods
>   are only applicable to instantiable 
>   types and static classes cannot be
>   instantiated.**

Check this code..

```
    public static bool IsEmail(this string email)
    {
        if (email != null)
        {
            return Regex.IsMatch(email, "EmailPattern");
        }

        return false;
    }
```

First parameter to **IsEmail()** is the extending type instance and not just the type itself. You can never have an instance of a static type.

Answer (score 10):

You can't extend static classes in C#. Extension methods work by defining static methods that appear as instance methods on some type. You can't define an extension method that extends a static class.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to turn your static class into a [singleton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998558.aspx). Then there will only be one instance of the class. And you can use extension methods on it because it's an instance.

This is provided you have access to the source code of the class.

Comment: Can we expect an explanation for this (I hate singleton)?

Comment: Well, you wouldn't expect just one instance of "I hate singleton", would you?

Comment: How can anyone delete my I hate singleton I hate singleton comment?

Comment: @acidzombie24: I liked your comment. Probably somebody with high privileges (& high score) deleted it for some reason, maybe they didn't understand the joke. This site is run by the members. Too bad that happened.