# Extension methods on a static object

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, extension-methods

I know (or so I hear) that writing extension methods for a single stand alone .net class (not an implementation of IEnumerable) is potential code smell. However, for the sake of making the life easier I need to attach a method to the ConfigurationManager class in asp.net. It's a static object so this won't work:

```
public static List<string> GetSupportedDomains(this ConfigurationManager manager) 
{

     //the manager needs to be static.

}
```

So the question is - is it possible to write an extension method for a static class in .net?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004416/extension-methods-on-a-static-class

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249222/can-i-add-extension-methods-to-an-existing-static-class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it isn't possible.

They are defined as static objects that appear to be *instance* methods.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx):

> Extension methods are defined as static methods but are called by using instance method syntax.

Answer (score 1):

No you can not. Extension methods require an instance of a given type, which you cannot get from a static class.